# appends duplicated in next object

Tags: python-3.x, append, repeat

I have two objects of the same class, which has an array property. After populating the first array, then the second, the second array prepends the values in the first.

```
from random import *
class Army:
    divisions = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
def rnd(max):
    return randint(0, max - 1)  
def init_army(i):
    army = Army(names[i])
    armies.append(army)
    divisions = rnd(num_divisions) + 1
    for i in range(divisions):
        army.divisions.append(rnd(num_divisions) + 1)
names = ["name1", "name2"]
armies = []
num_armies = 2
num_divisions = 6
for i in range(num_armies):
    init_army(i)
    print(armies[i].name, armies[i].divisions)
Typical Output:
name1 [5, 1]
name2 [5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
class Army:
    divisions = []
```

make `divisions` a class attribute.

Turn it into an instance attribute:

```
class Army:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.divisions = []
        self.name = name
```

In python there is no declaration. Instead, names (variables and attributes) are defined by assignment.

Where you assign things matters.

Please have a look at namespaces